# Unrecognized selector sent to instance Swift and URL

Tags: swift

On a intel chip Macbook Pro running Sonoma, I ran into an error trying to fetch an URL.  The foundation import doesn't seem to work very well using swift on the command line from tutorials found on the internet.  The `URL` seems to be lost and the compilation of the file results in a build error.  Below is the offending line:

```swift
let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")!
```

Here is the file in its entirety.

```swift
// The Swift Programming Language
// https://docs.swift.org/swift-book

import Foundation

let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")!
```

The error seems to be some kind of link issue or there's a problem with the foundation import when creating a command line application from the command line.

[image: error]

FUll error stack trace:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift.__SharedStringStorage mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000328e6a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8120540b6 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff811b49231 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8120f93a4 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff811fc1833 ___forwarding___ + 1379
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff811fc1248 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8120e9c70 _CFURLComponentsCreateWithStringInternal + 79
    6   Foundation                          0x00007ff8137237ce -[__NSConcreteURLComponents initWithString:encodingInvalidCharacters:] + 107
    7   Foundation                          0x00007ff813721a16 -[NSURL(NSURL) initWithString:relativeToURL:encodingInvalidCharacters:] + 277
    8   Foundation                          0x00007ff8131af3d8 $s10Foundation3URLV6stringACSgSSh_tcfC + 104
    9   Finsek.iOS                          0x0000000100002fea main + 138
    10  dyld                                0x00007ff811b7d3a6 start + 1942
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
Message from debugger: killed
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

### More Info

1. I created the project using `swift package init --type executable`
2. I opened up the main swift file with XCode, latest version 15, it opens up the project folder when doing so.
3. I did edit the package file to contain "ArgumentParser" but I'm not using it obviously.  But I'll still copy my package file here:

```swift
// swift-tools-version: 5.9
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MySwiftApp",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-argument-parser.git", from: "0.4.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package, defining a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package and products from dependencies.
        .executableTarget(
            name: "MySwiftApp",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "ArgumentParser", package: "swift-argument-parser")
            ]),
    ]
)
```

#### EDIT

Edits include better representation of the problem.

I've resolved this issue by simply using the Xcode application to create an app, and I'm able to continue forward developing out a command line application in that way.  I have other build tools on this machine for work, including dotnet, rust, homebrew, python env and other such things.  Because this is a dev machine, it's possible something is conflicting with it.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this but failed, alos on Xcode 15. Have you tried creating some other Foundation types instead of URL (in case there is something wrong with your installation of the Foundation framework)?

Comment: Could not replicate your error. Created a new Swift Package,
 `Xcode select File -> New -> Package`, added the code you show,
 and no errors. Note, you should be using `https:` as required by Apple.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - I tried adding: `var nsString: NSString = "hi"` and there wasn't an issue.  In fact, if I create a new project using the Xcode GUI, then it works.  IT DOES NOT WORK USING SWIFT FROM THE COMMAND LINE, meaning, if you were to try and create a new project using the command line, it for some reason does not work with the foundation framework appropriately I guess, I don't know or targets some legacy version.  Sheesh.  There's a disconnect there and I don't know what to do to fix it.

Comment: As a total beginner to Swift and Apple development, and someone who is well versed on the command line and fluent in other languages, my first impression isn't that good.  But I know that Apple makes great products and the creator of the language created Rust too and I like coding in Rust, so I'm going to continue giving it a shot.

Comment: One possible issue could be that the Xcode command line tools is of a different (older) version. Run `xcode-select -p` from the command line, it should point to your Xcode 15

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - It prints out: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: If you have only once version of Xcode install then it is correct. You could of course also check what swift version you have to be sure with `swift -version`, it should be 5.9

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - `swift-driver version: 1.87.1 Apple Swift version 5.9 (swiftlang-5.9.0.128.108 clang-1500.0.40.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx14.0` I'm on a macbook pro.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - I can write in an answer that has a fix: use the Xcode GUI to create an app.  I can not use the command line at this time until I understand the build infrastructure better.  I see that there is a difference between creating a command line project in Xcode and its organization and how it appears to work with packages and such, then creating a project using the swift command line utility.  There's probably room for improvement there.

Comment: No I don't think that is a useful answer since it works fine for most people to create a package from the command line.